# How to get multiple values for a data in cell based on single look up value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have sheet 1 in which A column is filled with maintasks and B column is filled with lookup values.

[image: Data]

Sheet 2 has range for lookup values. Column B in sheet 1 is same as column A in sheet2.

[image: Lookup range]

In sheet 3 I need maintask 
In sheet 1 (Column A) should be populated based on sub tasks in sheet2 (Column B) and budgeted hours in sheet 2 (Column C).

Please check the below output.

**Output:**

Solution should look for Column B in sheet1 and come back to sheet 2 and count the numbers of subtasks (column B) and populate the main task in sheet 1 (Column A) that many number of times including the content in subtasks and budgeted hours.

[image: Output]

I have tried using partial look up and other formalas but am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the table in the second sheet to the table in the first.

So below an Option 1 with **PowerQuery** and 2 with **VBA-SQL**

**Option 1:**

You can do this with the free add-in [PowerQuery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379=) (in built in 2016).

1) Set your data up in sheet 1 and 2 as tables (click in a populated cell within the data range and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> > select my table has headers.

[image: Table in sheet1]

2) Highlight each table and then go to `data` tab (2016) or `Powerquery` tab (2010-2013) and create new query data from table (`Get and Transform`)

This will pop up a query editor window showing your table (the query/table you can rename on the right hand side)

[image: Query > from table]

3) You can then select close and `load to > only create connection`  (from top left hand corner of window

[image: Close and load icon]

Choosing connection only

[image: connection only table load]

Repeat for tables in sheet 1 and 2.

4) Then create new query > combine queries > merge

[image: merging queries]

Make sure your sub tasks table is the first table selected and Main tasks is second. Click on `Content_Category_Product Sub Type` columns in both tables so they are highlighted (this will be the join column)

Check that `join kind`  is `Left outer` and that there is a green tick for selection matching.

Then click ok and load to sheet3.

[image: Merging tables]

5) Sort the resulting table on first column ascending

[image: Sort on Main tasks]

6) View result :

[image: Result table]

There are plenty of resources about `Powerquery` you can look up. This will allow you to change column names etc. You can also delete unwanted columns to match image you posted.

**Or Option 2:**

With SQL, adapting an approach from [barrowc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15181759/outer-join-in-ms-excel), and a function by [Johan Kreszner](http://%20'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro/28879494), making sure you go to the VBA editor (Alt-F11) and add a reference (`Tools > References`) to "`Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects X.X Library`".

I have assumed only the tables are in sheet 1 and 2 but otherwise you may need to alter the SQL to target the ranges of the tables (List Objects) which is why i have included Johan's function to return the range of a list object provided you pass the table name as a string.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LeftJoinTables()

    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
                            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;IMEX=1;HDR=YES"";"
        .Open
    End With

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    rs.Open "SELECT [Main Task], [Sub Task], [Budget Hours] FROM [Sheet2$] LEFT JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet2$].[Content Category_Product Sub type] = " & _
            "[Sheet1$].[Content Category_Product Sub type] ORDER BY [Main Task]", cn

    Dim fld As ADODB.Field
    Dim i As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        i = 0
        For Each fld In rs.Fields
            i = i + 1
            .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
        Next fld
        .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
        .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

    rs.Close
    cn.Close

End Sub



Public Function GetRange(ByVal sListName As String) As String

Dim oListObject As ListObject
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
    For Each oListObject In ws.ListObjects
        If oListObject.Name = sListName Then
            GetRange = "[" & ws.Name & "$" & Replace(oListObject.Range.Address, "$", "") & "]"
        Exit Function
        End If
    Next oListObject
Next ws

End Function
```